# Moodle import course or plugin

Tags: moodle

I've been asked by a client to create a course and a teacher area within moodle for them.

The problem lies in that I have no access to their system. So il have to code it myself then import it to their system.

Can this be done?? would I be able to export everything related to the course and then import it to their systems?

or a plugin?

Thank you.

Comment: You could install Moodle locally, create the course and then use course backup on your local moodle, then restore on their system - https://docs.moodle.org/28/en/Course_backup

Comment: Thanks! I think my question was rather obvious!